# APIv4 Base URL for external applications

Tags: wordpress, api, apiv4

I am trying to write an external app with python, that should make a call to the CiviCRM's APIv4 to get a list of contacts & relationships.

I am using CiviCRM's with Wordpress and debian 11.

Wordpress is installed under /var/www/wordpress

I am having problems to find the correct base URL to make calls to the APIv4.

I got it working with v3 using `http://192.168.100.168:8166/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Relationship&key={site_key}&json=1&debug=1&version=3&api_key={myApiKey}&action=get`

If I try, like is said in the docs, to call `http://192.168.100.168:8166/civicrm/ajax/api4/Relationship/get` I get a `404 NotFound` error.

Thats what I see in the REST tab in API Explorer 4

[image]

How should I call the APIv4?

Answer (score 2):

How about
http://192.168.100.168:8166/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/ajax/api4/Relationship/get

You can check the REST tab in API4 explorer for correct url

Comment: Your URL didn't work. Please see my updated question, with an image of the REST tab,

Comment: Updated the url